# Codeigniter add to favorites ajax logic advice

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a problem what i really cant solve.

I am makeing an ajax insiter for saveing to favorites function, it works fine.

But since its not uesing a form im a bit lost at the logic.

What i would like to do is when the user click on the button it changes yellow and stays yellow if the user cliks again it removes from the favorites and changes back to blue.

I dont want anybody to write this for me i just need some hint or advice for the logic.

Here is my code

jquery

```
//save to favorites
$('.favorite').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = [],
    newclass = 'btn-warning',
    oldcalss = 'btn-primary',
    fav = $(this);
    favId = fav.attr('id'),

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: base_url + 'ajax/add_favorite/' + favId,
        success: function(result)
        {
            fav.removeClass(oldcalss)
            .addClass(newclass);    
        }
    });

});
```

model

```
function insert_favorite($id)
{
    $favData = array(
        'job_id' => $id,
        'uid' => $this->session->userdata('user_id')
    );

    $this->db->insert('job_favorites', $favData);
}
```

html

```
<?php if($this->ion_auth->logged_in()): ?>
 <a href="#" id="<?php echo $res->info_id; ?>" class="favorite btn btn-primary btn-mini" title="Add to favorite"><i class="icon-star icon-white"></i></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check whether the job id is in the database and return a value to AJAX function:

```
function insert_favorite($id)
{

    if (!is_numeric($id)) {
        exit;
    }

    $this->db->where('job_id', $id);
    $this->db->where('uid', $this->session->userdata('user_id'));
    $row = $this->db->get('job_favorites')->row();

    //There is a previous value
    if ($row) {
        $this->db->where('job_id', $row->id);
        $this->db->where('uid', $this->session->userdata('user_id'));           
        $this->db->delete('job_favorites');
        echo json_encode(array('result' => 'exists'));
    }
    else {
        $favData = array(
            'job_id' => $id,
            'uid' => $this->session->userdata('user_id')
         );

        $this->db->insert('job_favorites', $favData);
        echo json_encode(array('result' => 'new'));
    }
}
```

In the callback function change the color of the button according to the result variable.

I recommend moving the db calls and logic to a model and leaving as less logic as possible in the controller.